# Framesets and leftnavigation pane e.g

Tags: javascript, html, frame

How to use framesets in such a way that there is a left pane which is of navigational purpose, i.e by clicking on a link in left pane one can navigate to the corresponding page in the middle frame?

I could get that target attribute can be used to achieve this. can anyone help me with the same.

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to do, but keep in mind that the `frame` element is deprecated in HTML5. Perhaps it's time for you to take another approach

Comment: actually i was learning html+javascript i wanted to have a sample leftnavigation.htm with links which when clicked would open the linked page in the centerPage.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks user1370510, got a nice tutorial for Html frames, sharing the same for anyone else coming with the same question:-
http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/frames/frames_famsupp_5.html

Answer (score 0):

Divide the page in to two frames: one for navigation links, and the other for content. Use target for links, like this:

```
<a href='' target='conetent_frame'></a>
```